# How do I find an Object in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

using angular,
i have an array

```
list: Employee[] = [
    {id: 1, name: "conrad", email: "conrad@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Admin"},
    {id: 2, name: "two", email: "2@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Finance"},
    {id: 3, name: "three", email: "3@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Finance"},
    {id: 4, name: "four", email: "4@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 5, name: "five", email: "5@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 6, name: "six", email: "6@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 7, name: "seven", email: "7@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"},
    {id: 8, name: "eight", email: "8@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"},
    {id: 9, name: "nine", email: "9@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"}
  ];
```

then i have an object

```
data = {name: "conrad", email: "conrad@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Admin", id: 1}
```

how do i find out if data is present in list
i have tried following gives answer as undefined

```
signUp(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.list.find(l => l === data));
  }
```

also tried some, includes.

Comment: You can't compare objects using `===`

Comment: use loadash `_.isEqual(object, other)`

Comment: [This](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html) explains why it doesn't work, and how to solve the issue:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Array.prototype.some()` to check if your list contains a specific employee-`Object`

```js
list = [
    {id: 1, name: "conrad", email: "conrad@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Admin"},
    {id: 2, name: "two", email: "2@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Finance"},
    {id: 3, name: "three", email: "3@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Finance"},
    {id: 4, name: "four", email: "4@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 5, name: "five", email: "5@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 6, name: "six", email: "6@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Marketing"},
    {id: 7, name: "seven", email: "7@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"},
    {id: 8, name: "eight", email: "8@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"},
    {id: 9, name: "nine", email: "9@test.com", password: "123456", department: "Service"}
  ];
  
  function employeeIsInList(employee, list) {
    return list.some((listEmployee) => {
      return employee.id === listEmployee.id;
    });
  }
  
  console.log(
    'employee with id 3 is in the list, therefore result is',
    employeeIsInList({id: 3, name: "three"}, list)
  ); //true
  
  console.log(
    'employee with id 100 is not in the list, therefore result is',
    employeeIsInList({id: 100, name: "woswasi"}, list)
  ); //false
```